# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 3: invalid start byte

Tags: python, hex, typeconverter

I am using Python 3 but found this error in server log while doing convert format from string to byte

```
b'\x00\x01_\x97'.decode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    b'\x00\x01_\x97'.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 3: invalid start byte
```

How can I convert a string to its byte value? I

Comment: which version of python you using ?

Comment: its Python 3.6.3

Comment: How your output should be ? in which type ?

Comment: i want to remove b'' from this line data

Comment: what is the encoding used "utf-8" or "utf-16" ?

Comment: this is 'utf-8'

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the encoding type `Latin` by

```
>>> b'\x00\x01_\x97'.decode("Latin")
   '\x00\x01_\x97'
>>> type(b'\x00\x01_\x97'.decode("Latin"))
   <class 'str'>
>>>
```

Comment: @Doctor PC: Please confirm whether you solved your error

Comment: @Doctor PC: Is this what you are expecting ?